# LINQ select out list of values and map into one field property in the nested class structure

Tags: c#, linq

Animal:

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| animalId | animal  | typeId |
+----------+---------+--------+
|    1     | snake   |   1    |
|    2     | cat     |   2    |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

AnimalType:

```
+--------+----------+
| typeId |   type   |
+--------+----------+
|   1    | reptile  |
|   2    | mammal   |
+--------+----------+
```

AnimalBody:

```
+--------+-------+----------+
| bodyId | body  | animalId |
+--------+-------+----------+
|    1   | tail  |    1     |
|    2   | eye   |    1     |
|    3   | tail  |    2     |
|    4   | eye   |    2     |
|    5   | leg   |    2     |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

Table relation:

- Animal.typeId = AnimalType.typeId
- Animal.animalId = AnimalBody.animalId

**I need to output them into JSON format as below:**

```
{
   animalId: 1,
   animal: "snake",
   type: "reptile",
   body: {
      "tail", "eye"
   }
}, 
{
   animalId: 2,
   animal: "cat",
   type: "mammal",
   body: {
      "tail", "eye", "leg"
   }
}
```

**How can I achieve this with pure LINQ clauses instead of method?**

**I have tried:**

```
from animal in db.Animal 
join animalType in db.AnimalType on animal.typeId equals animalType.typeId
select new 
{
   animalId = animal.animalId,
   animal = animal.animal,
   type = animalType.type,
   body = ?
};
```

Comment: Please add code that gets sample collections. And show what you tried to clarify what you want.

Comment: Instead of tables, show us your entities, Do they have navigation properties for these relations?

Comment: @MathewJibin pls read the post clearly, I have included the table relations at the first place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the `body` element to be an array of body parts, here's what you should do:
Join `Animal`s with `AnimalType`s:

```
var animalsWithType = db.Animals.Join(
    animal => animal.typeId,
    animalType => animalType.typeId,
    (animal, type) => new { animal, type });
```

Afterwards, [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) `animalsWithType` with `AnimalBody` elements:

```
var result = animalsWithType.GroupJoin(db.AnimalBodies,
    animalWithType => animalWithType.animal.animalId,
    body => body.animalId,
    (animalWithType, bodyParts) => new
    {
        animalId = animalWithType.animal.animalId,
        animal = animalWithType.animal.animal,
        type = animalWithType.type.type,
        body = bodyParts.Select(part => part.body)
    });
```

Now, just export the `result` to JSON and you should be set.

Comment: thanks in advance, may i know how to use LINQ using clauses instead of method?